# Relation on a multi-valued field in an Access database

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

Does someone know how I can put more than one value in one field to make a relation between two different records?

**Google translation (from German):**

> Using multivalued fields
>
> In most systems, DBMS (database management systems), including earlier
>   versions of Microsoft Access, you can only store a single value in a
>   field. In Microsoft Office Access 2007, you can also create fields
>   that contain multiple values​​, such as a list of categories to which
>   you have assigned a condition. Multivalued fields are used in specific
>   situations, such as when you use Office Access 2007 to work saved in a
>   Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 list that contains a field of one of
>   the field types with multiple values ​​that are available in Windows
>   data SharePoint Services.
>
> This topic describes how to create and use multivalued fields in
>   Office Access 2007 and Windows SharePoint Services, how to create
>   multivalued fields and used, and how to use multivalued fields in a
>   query.

Comment: Asking your question in a language people can understand would help.

Comment: That is an interesting question to me since I dealt with this problem a year ago.  My solution was to store the multiple values as a delimited string.  Then, instead of a regular join between 2 tables, I used a custom VBA function to parse the string and compare each value to the values from the other table.  The result was slow and confusing but workable. If there is a better solution, I'm listening.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multi-value Lookup fields in JOIN conditions (via their `.Value` property), but be aware that if there is such a field on both sides of the join then it will produce a match when *any* item matches on the joined fields, not when *all* items match. This may or may not be desirable, depending on the situation.

**Case 1: Students with allergies**

A school administrator needs to keep track of students with allergies and provide them with a list of meals that they should avoid when eating at the school cafeteria.

[Students]

```
ID  Student  Allergies
--  -------  ---------
1   Alice    Eggs, Soy
2   Bradley  Peanuts
3   Carol    
4   Dennis   Soy
```

[Meals]

```
ID  Meal           Allergens
--  -------------  ---------
1   Thai stir-fry  Peanuts
2   Tofu omlette   Eggs, Soy
3   Waffles        Eggs
```

The query

```sql
SELECT Students.Student, Students.Allergies, Meals.Meal, Meals.Allergens
FROM Students INNER JOIN Meals ON Students.Allergies.Value = Meals.Allergens.Value;
```

returns

```
Student  Allergies  Meal           Allergens
-------  ---------  -------------  ---------
Alice    Eggs, Soy  Tofu omlette   Eggs, Soy
Alice    Eggs, Soy  Waffles        Eggs
Bradley  Peanuts    Thai stir-fry  Peanuts
Dennis   Soy        Tofu omlette   Eggs, Soy
```

This is appropriate, since Alice should avoid meals that contain *any* ingredients to which she is allergic.

**Case 2: Hotel requirements**

[Travellers]

```
ID  Traveller  Requirements
--  ---------  -------------------------
1   Gord       free WiFi, in-room coffee
```

[Hotels]

```
ID  Hotel         Amenities
--  ------------  ----------------------------
1   Budget Motel  free WiFi, in-room coffee
2   Fancy Hotel   in-room coffee, room service
```

The query

```sql
SELECT Travellers.Traveller, Travellers.Requirements, Hotels.Hotel, Hotels.Amenities
FROM Hotels INNER JOIN Travellers ON Hotels.Amenities.Value = Travellers.Requirements.Value;
```

returns

```
Traveller  Requirements               Hotel         Amenities
---------  -------------------------  ------------  ----------------------------
Gord       free WiFi, in-room coffee  Budget Motel  free WiFi, in-room coffee
Gord       free WiFi, in-room coffee  Fancy Hotel   in-room coffee, room service
```

The query returns both properties because they both offer in-room coffee. However, Fancy Hotel does not offer free WiFi, so I would prefer not to stay there. In this case the default join behaviour is not desirable (to me).